# `pip install docker-py` vs `pip install 'molecule[docker]'`?

Tags: python, docker, molecule

I have seen people using `pip install docker-py` or  `pip install 'molecule[docker]'`.

I believe they are similar (equivalent?)

I read https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html
which says :

> Molecule requires an external Python dependency for the Docker driver which is provided when installing Molecule using `pip install 'molecule[docker]'`.

so is the `molecule[docker]` one better in some way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install molecule[docker]` is special pip syntax to say "install the [`molecule` package](https://pypi.org/project/molecule/), with its additional `docker` option".  Using this is almost certainly better than installing `molecule` with no additional options, and then trying to manually install its Docker dependencies separately.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that `pip install docker-py` install the library globally, or installs the entire library.

Whereas `pip install molecule[docker]` either only installs the necessary bits for molecule, or it installs it specifically in a molecule location.

I'm more inclined to believe it's the first option - that it saves on space and resources by only installing what is necessary. But that is just my guess.